# Ubuntu 18.04 disconnects from Win10 RDP after exactly 30 min

Tags: suspend, power-management, remote-desktop, x11rdp

Dell Precision 7520 Ubuntu 18.04 laptop with xrdp installed. Self built Windows 10 makes RDP Remote Desktop Protocol connection to Ubuntu machine on local network. Exactly at 30 minutes connection is dropped, Ubuntu goes in Suspend mode. Hit keyboard on Ubuntu machine and no problem reconnecting.
On Ubuntu 18.04 Settings->Power->Suspend & Power Button Automatic Suspend is set to 45 minutes on Battery Power. When connected through Win10 RDP the Settings->Power->Suspend & Power Button in not visible.
Dell Bios Power Management->Wake on LAN/WLAN is set to Wake-On-LAN 
Any ideas on how to override automatic suspend setting when connecting from Win10 RDP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I also encountered the same issue with a Dell 5550 Laptop with Ubuntu 20.04. Wifi and Ethernet connectivity dies after exactly 30 minutes when connecting via RDP from Windows.

My not so great solution was to

- Create a secondary user `sudo adduser {new username goes here}`,
- Login as that secondary user on the laptop
- Install and run caffeine with that secondary account. That will prevent the laptop from going to sleep and the RDP connection stays up for the main account on my Windows Machine.

There might be a better solution but for now this is what I have done to solve this quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the situation is Ubuntu 18.04 still drops the network connection exactly after 30 minutes. 
One workaround is "sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target". (Sends everything to /dev/null symlink.) This for some reason only drops the first 30 minute disconnection from Ubuntu. Of course all data is lost since nothing is saved after the connection is dropped. Then after logging back on the 2nd time through Win 10 RDP no more drops. But this is only a workaround. I still need to know how to stop Ubuntu 18.04 from dropping the network connection after 30 minutes.